# PHP: how to turn multidimensional array to single dimension dynamically

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, array-merge

I have an array like that

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "2012-05-23"
    [1]=>
    string(10) "2012-05-31"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "2012-05-30"
    [1]=>
    string(10) "2012-06-07"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "2012-06-02"
    [1]=>
    string(10) "2012-06-07"
    }
}
```

I want turn this array into

```
  array(6) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "2012-05-23"
    [1]=>
    string(10) "2012-05-31"
    [2]=>
    string(10) "2012-05-30"
    [3]=>
    string(10) "2012-06-07"
    [4]=>
    string(10) "2012-06-02"
    [5]=>
    string(10) "2012-06-07"
    }
```

and I want to do it dynamically. I mean I could have an array here with 100 dimensions. So must be something in loop :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$final_array =array();
foreach ($data as $val)
 {
    foreach($val as $val2)
     {
        $final_array[] = $val2;
     }
 }
```

Comment: You might want to turn this into a recursive function so it still works no matter how many dimensions the array has.

Comment: @Steven1978 : take a look to mine

Answer (score 3):

```
function makeArray($finalArray,$element) {
 foreach ($element as $key => $value){
  if(is_array($value)) makeArray($finalArray,$value);
  else $finalArray[] = $value;
 }
}
```

If you want a "general-pourpose" solution, this is the one

Obviously you have to call it, the first time, with `$finalArray` as an empty Array and `$element` as your starting array

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code:

```
$it =  new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($data));

$l = iterator_to_array($it, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

There's heaps of flattening strategies in the php docs comments:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php

Answer (score 1):

I would just use Underscore ;)
http://brianhaveri.github.com/Underscore.php/

Comment: Looks useful.. worth a try (:

Answer (score 0):

Simple search returned this from [PHP.net docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php#104184)

```
<?php 
/** 
 * Flattens an array, or returns FALSE on fail. 
 */ 
function array_flatten($array) { 
  if (!is_array($array)) { 
    return FALSE; 
  } 
  $result = array(); 
  foreach ($array as $key => $value) { 
    if (is_array($value)) { 
      $result = array_merge($result, array_flatten($value)); 
    } 
    else { 
      $result[$key] = $value; 
    } 
  } 
  return $result; 
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you're looking for

[array walk recursive](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) function

> Applies the user-defined function funcname to each element of the
>   input array. This function will recurse into deeper arrays.